# Antonym for improved

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Im looking for an antonym for the word improved.

For this sentence:

> Last time he improved, but this time he ________

I would prefer one word.

Comment: How about _deteriorated_?

Comment: @Charon you beat me to my answer :)

Comment: Can you clarify what’s improving (and then not improving)? If it’s his piano skills we’re talking about “deteriorate” is completely inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **deteriorated**.

You could say:

> Last time he improved but this time he deteriorated

The defenition is:

> become progressively worse

Which is the opposite of improve.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of grading human performance, I would say:

> Last time he improved, but this time he **regressed.**

regress    [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/regress)
v. **regressed**

> - To return to a previous, usually worse or less developed state: When    I left the country, my ability to speak the language
>     regressed.
> - To have a tendency to approach or go back to a statistical mean.
> - To move backward or away from a reference point; recede: The seas regressed as the glaciers grew larger.